# Can't get Django image to display

Tags: django, image

I'm having trouble getting my image files to appear from the database info.  If I type the filename directly, it works fine, but the code as it is shows a broken image.  The non-image variables work fine, and the image is stored in the model as a CharField of the filename (which I realize now may not have been best, but I think it may be too late to change?)  What am I doing wrong?

```
<div class="product_image" >
        {% load static %} <img src="{% static "images/{{p.image.url}}" %}" alt={{p.name}}/>
```

(I've also tried {{p.image}} with no luck.)

Here are the relevant settings--still confused about media vs static.

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'media')

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'staticcoll')

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static'),
)
```

Here is the Product model (p):

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9,decimal_places=2)
    old_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9,decimal_places=2,
                                    blank=True,default=0.00)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="imagenotfound.jpeg")
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    store_name = models.ForeignKey(Store, blank = True, null = True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'products'
        ordering = ['-created_at']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: I have definitely been here before when starting out with Django.  Why are you using a CharField to store the image?  Is it a full or relative path or URL?

Comment: I'm not sure why I did it that way, other than I'm still learning.  When I view the page source after loading, I get:

<img src="/static/images/{{p.image}}" alt=X-Men Action Figures/>

Which surprised me; I had thought I would get a full path.  Nonetheless, a similar static image elsewhere--where I typed the name of the file rather than using a variable--worked fine.  Does it have something to do with the variable being inside the string, so it doesn't get rendered?  I tried putting it outside the quotes but it raised a SyntaxError.

Comment: If you're using [south](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/0.7.6/tutorial/part1.html) you could write a custom migration to convert the char field to an [ImageField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#imagefield)

Comment: I'll second @Nathaniel, if you are not using South you should start.  It will provide a pretty painless way for you to convert your image CharField to an ImageField.

Comment: I will check it out, but I have to submit this code for an interview tomorrow, and it's far from done.  Considering I've only been doing Django for four days, the list of things to learn before tomorrow is already quite long...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's just the file name stored in `p.image.url`, this will work:

`<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/{{p.image}}" alt={{p.name}}/>`

You must have `context = RequestContext(request)` in your view for `{{ STATIC_URL }}` to work.

You can read about `RequestContext` [here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext)

Comment: I'll check--should I include the {% load static %} or no?  (Tried both and neither worked)

Comment: Actually, it's the same either way:
  <img src="/images/" alt=X-Men Action Figures/>

Comment: Without the .url, I get:  
<img src="/images/xmen.jpg" alt=X-Men Action Figures/>

Edited to correct db error.

Comment: What is p.url?  Is that something built-in or something I should defined?  (If you're responding to the comment I had edited above, I realized that for that specific instance I just hadn't entered the extension, so that was my fault and is fixed)

Comment: In your `settings.py`, do you have `'django.core.context_processors.static'` in your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`? If not, that would cause the `{{ STATIC_URL }}` not to load.

Comment: Also, see `EDIT2` of my original post. If you are not using `RequestContext` when rendering your template, then `STATIC_URL` will not work.

Comment: I did not.  I added it, and it raised an error telling me to add another one.  Here's what it looks like now:

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = ('django.core.context_processors.static', 
        'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',)

It doesn't raise an error, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I think we're getting closer:  I did not have the `{% load staticfiles %}` which I now do.  (I am not using RequestContext--that's new to me, I have to go read the docs on it.)  The images are not rendering, but the broken image icon changed shape to what I believe is the width of the correct picture (they're all different, anyway).  Here's the source now:  <img src="/static/images/{{p.image}}" alt="X-Men Action Figures"/>

Comment: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value: 
Could not parse the remainder: 'p.image' from '"images/"p.image'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23331/discussion-between-dan-hoerst-and-thumbtackthief)

Answer (score 2):

You can't nest the Django tags like that.

If p.image is a CharField, use

```
<img src="{% static p.image %}" alt="{{p.name}}"/>
```

You'll need to make sure the correct path is stored in the field.

Comment: The file is stored in static/images.  Does that matter?  It's not working as is.